# Java Bitwise AND operator

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, mask

I'm trying to mask an integer in order to separate each byte individually like so:

```
     int a = (0xffffffff & 0xff000000) >> 24;
     int b = (0xffffffff & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
     int c = (0xffffffff & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
     int d = 0xffffffff & 0x000000ff;
```

b, c and d give the correct answer in this case, 255, however, a continues to give me -1 and other negative numbers no matter what I change it to, I even tried:

```
             int a = (0xefffffff & 0xff000000) >> 24;
```

and it gives me -17.

Does someone know how do I solve this problem so that in this boundary case a gives me 255 and other positive numbers?

Comment: PS in your second attempt, do you mean to mask a value whose top bit is not set? That's `0x7fffffff` not `0xefffffff`

Comment: I recommend reading the following: http://www.javamex.com/java_equivalents/unsigned.shtml

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because of sign extension. If the top-most bit is 1, then `>>` shifts in 1s. This is to preserve the sign of the argument. You want to use `>>>` which always shifts in 0. Or, mask after the shift:

```
int a = (0xffffffff >> 24) & 0x000000ff;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a signed shift, so the sign is preserved.

```
int a = (0xffffffff & 0xff000000) >>> 24; // unsigned shift.
```

or

```
int a = 0xffffffff >>> 24; // unsigned shift and all the bottom bits are lost anyway
int b = (0xffffffff >>> 16) & 0xFF;
int c = (0xffffffff >>> 8) & 0xFF;
int d = 0xffffffff & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an `unsigned shifting`,

Try it this way...

`(0xffffffff & 0xff000000) >>> 24`